# A Word A Day for Chinese

Tags: word, resources, dictionary

Does anyone know of any Chinese service that sends or publishes a regular A Word A Day for native Chinese speakers to expand their own vocabulary? I'm having trouble finding one, even though these are really easy to find for English (e.g. Merriam-Webster, Oxford English Dictionary).

Comment: iciba:每日一句 e.g. July 25: With equal passion I have sought knowledge. I have wished to understand the hearts of men. I have wished to know why the stars shine.
我用同样的激情去寻求知识。我希望能理解人类的心灵，希望能够知道群星为何闪烁。

Comment: LINE dictionary:Today's expressions

他非常喜欢出风头。Today's quotes

哪里有天才，我是把别人喝咖啡的时间都用在工作上的。Today's proverbs

一叶障目，不见泰山。pinyin, English, sound at http://ce.linedict.com/#/cnen/home

Comment: Most Chinese native spearkers won't think about or need "expanding their vocabulary" once they graduated middle school because the nature of Chinese language is quite different from western languages. But some "A Quote A Day" services are quite popular.

Answer (score 1):

Transparent Language ® offers [Mandarin Chinese Word of the Day](https://www.transparent.com/word-of-the-day/today/chinese.html)
which can be retrieved in multiple ways:

- visit web page
- daily email (subscribe form via link above)
- RSS feed
- Twitter

*Contains*: Character, Pinyin, Translation, Example Sentence (all with audio pronunciation, slow and fast)

[image: promotion image: wotd]

Answer (score 0):

you may try the international encoded han chinese and variants database (國際電腦漢字及異體字知識庫)

http://chardb.iis.sinica.edu.tw/

actually, it's "one han chinese character a day" service, in traditional srcipt; they even have an android app :)

have fun :)

Comment: The Android app is not listed in GooglePlay store. Is there any **link to the mentioned app** you can post?